# Drop down onchange event to get the amount in the tex tbox in ajax from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I change my drop down i didn't get the amount in my text box.

anything wrong in this code? Do I need  to change the function?

Database table name is product

e.x:

```
pid product  amount
1   phone     1500
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="product">product name</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="product" name="product" onChange="getamount(this.value);">
          <option value="">Select product</option>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

          <label for="amount">amount</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="amount" name="amount" readonly>

      </div>
```

**Ajax function:**

```
function getamount(val) {
  alert(val);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_amount.php",
    data:'pid='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#amount").html(data);
    }
    });
}
```

get_amount.php

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
if(!empty($_POST["pid"])) 
{
$query =mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT amount FROM product WHERE pid= '" . $_POST["pid"] . "'");
?>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
{
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php $row['amount]?>">
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any questions here! Is there anything wrong with your code?

Comment: Hi Sir , i change my drop down  i didn't get the amount in my text box. thanks in advance

Comment: Edit this into your question please!

Comment: ok sir, Thank You

Comment: incomplete html code. select element doesn't have a value to pass through javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html code, there is no closing select-tag, the value of the option field is empty, and there is no other option so onchange will not trigger.
I also changed the data of the ajax call in your getamount function.
This is how i tested it, to get it working:

```js
function getamount(val) {
  alert(val);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_amount.php",
    data: {
      pid: val
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#amount").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="product">product name</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="product" name="product" onChange="getamount(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select product</option>
    <option value="1">Select product1</option>
    <option value="2">Select product2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="amount">amount</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="amount" name="amount" readonly>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank You.it Works  I also change my get_amount.php code

Comment: ` ` ` <?php
require_once("db.php");
if(!empty($_POST["end_id"])) 
{
$query =mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM endplace WHERE id = '" . $_POST["end_id"] . "'");
?>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
{
   echo $row['amount'];
?>
<?php
}
}
?>
  ` ` `